# Stack overflow error due to large amount of calculations

Tags: c#, image-processing, stack-overflow

I am just looking for a efficient way for the following code since I get an stack overflow error, I gave as much as info I can but maybe you don't need all these explanations but just the code itself would suffice, any help would be appreciated to make me get ride of this error;

What I am trying to do applying an operator (Hueckel edge detection operator) to an 9x9 area at a time and repeat it for the whole image. So it is a regular edge detection fundamental. You can see what I mean at the second picture.

[image] [image]

Function a() is being called 8 times in another function called hueckel_operator() at a time and hueckel_operator is a recursive function which call itself +5 for both x and y parameters every time. That means a() is being called pretty much for the big images and the real problem MyImage[] which is an emgucv Image<> object. Because MyImage[] should check every pixel in a 9x9 matrix and bring the value of it, it is being called 69 * j times more than the function a().

Function input_i_y() brings the y coordinate and there is another function called input_i_x() which brings the x coordinate of the 9x9 matrix. I know, it is extreme to make two seperate function in order to use them as parameter of another function but I couldn't find any better solution. HueckelDisk class is calculating the formula of the 9 different hueckel disks according to the x,y coordinates. According to the fitting accuracy we become sure if there is an edge or not.

[image]

here is the terminating condition of the hueckel_operator()

```
if (mod_width + counter4 + 10 >= MyImage.Width && mod_height + counter5 + 10 >= MyImage.Height)
            {
                goto EXIT2;
            }
```

here is the beginning and end of the hueckel_operator()

```
public void hueckel_operator(int counter2, int counter3)
        {      
            counter2 = counter4;
            counter3 = counter5;

               int mod_width = MyImage.Width % 5;
            int mod_height = MyImage.Height % 5;

            if (mod_width + counter4 + 10 >= MyImage.Width && mod_height + counter5 + 10 >= MyImage.Height)
            {
                goto EXIT2;
            }
            else
            {
                if (mod_width + counter4 + 10 >= MyImage.Width)
                {
                    if (counter5 == 1)
                    {
                        counter5 += 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        counter5 += 5;
                    }
                    counter4 = 1;
                }
                if (counter4 == 1)
                {
                    counter4 += 4;
                }

                else if(counter4 != 0)

                {
                    counter4 += 5;
                }

                if (counter5 == 0 && counter4 == 0)
                {
                    counter4 = 1;
                    counter5 = 1;
                }
            }
```

Here is the end of the hueckel_operator();

EXIT:

```
               hueckel_operator(counter5, counter4);

        EXIT2:

            MessageBox.Show("done");
        }
```

here is the function a()

```
 public double a(int j,  int counter6,  int counter7)
                {

                    double result = 0;

                    HueckelDisks hueckel_formula = new HueckelDisks();

                    counter6 = counter4;
                    counter7 = counter5;


                    for (int II = 0; II <= j ; II++)
                    {
                        for (KK = 1; KK < 69; KK++)
                        {

                            result += hueckel_formula.HueckelDisk(input_i_x(KK),input_i_y(KK),j) * MyImage[point_a, point_b].Intensity;

                        }
                    }

                    return result;
                }


         public int input_i_y(int y)
                {        
                    Tuple<int, int>[] myArray =
                    {
                        Tuple.Create(3,1),Tuple.Create(4,1),Tuple.Create(5,1),Tuple.Create(6,1),Tuple.Create(7,1),Tuple.Create(2,2),
                        Tuple.Create(3,2),Tuple.Create(4,2),Tuple.Create(5,2),Tuple.Create(6,2),Tuple.Create(7,2),Tuple.Create(8,2),
                        Tuple.Create(1,3),Tuple.Create(2,3),Tuple.Create(3,3),Tuple.Create(4,3),Tuple.Create(5,3),Tuple.Create(6,3),
                        Tuple.Create(7,3),Tuple.Create(8,3),Tuple.Create(9,3),Tuple.Create(1,4),Tuple.Create(2,4),Tuple.Create(3,4),
                        Tuple.Create(4,4),Tuple.Create(5,4),Tuple.Create(6,4),Tuple.Create(7,4),Tuple.Create(8,4),Tuple.Create(9,4),
                        Tuple.Create(1,5),Tuple.Create(1,5),Tuple.Create(2,5),Tuple.Create(3,5),Tuple.Create(4,5),Tuple.Create(5,5),
                        Tuple.Create(6,5),Tuple.Create(7,5),Tuple.Create(8,5),Tuple.Create(9,5),Tuple.Create(1,6),Tuple.Create(2,6),
                        Tuple.Create(3,6),Tuple.Create(4,6),Tuple.Create(5,6),Tuple.Create(6,6),Tuple.Create(7,6),Tuple.Create(8,6),
                        Tuple.Create(8,6),Tuple.Create(1,7),Tuple.Create(2,7),Tuple.Create(3,7),Tuple.Create(4,7),Tuple.Create(5,7),
                        Tuple.Create(6,7),Tuple.Create(7,7),Tuple.Create(8,7),Tuple.Create(9,7),Tuple.Create(2,8),Tuple.Create(3,8),
                        Tuple.Create(4,8),Tuple.Create(5,8),Tuple.Create(6,8),Tuple.Create(7,8),Tuple.Create(8,8),Tuple.Create(3,9),
                        Tuple.Create(4,9),Tuple.Create(5,9),Tuple.Create(6,9),Tuple.Create(7,9),

                    };


                    return myArray[y].Item2;


                }
```

Comment: The stack overflow is from recursion.  The code you've posted contains none.  So we probably need to see different code.

Comment: Stack overflow is typically associated with unbounded recursion (i.e. a function keeps calling itself without a "base case" that causes the recursion to terminate).  So I'd check that your code is correct first.  When the code is correct but the calculation is still giving a stack overflow, it usually means you've come up with an algorithm so inefficient it will never complete in a reasonable amount of time.  And finally, your function `input_i_y` creates and initialises a new array every time you call it.  This doesn't explain the stack overflow, but it will be very slow.

Comment: @arx I am editting my question, you can see if it is bounded or not but it is stucked and throw stack overflow at the x=70, y=1 for a picture 600x800

Comment: That's still not enough code for anyone else to understand what's going on.  Try having a look at the call stack when you get the stack overflow error.  How many nested function calls do you see?  I'd be very surprised if there aren't many more than 69.  Note that each recursive call multiplies the total number of calls made.

Comment: @DonRoby I have also add the beginning and end of the recursion function. And Tuple.Create is allocating %65 of the memory. I actually need an array or something similar which holdes the x,y coordinates but initialised just once not 69 * j times. I guess Tuple.Create is causing the mess.

Comment: @arx I couldnt manage to find out the total number of calls made but I am working on it

Comment: please check out creating the `myArray` outside the `input_i_y` this one can be static, it will not change in between calls. but, to be honest, this will not be the overall problem here. it just bloats the stack. you could write an initialize function which creates the myArray only once!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check out creating the `myArray` outside of `input_i_y`.

it even could be static as it will not change in between calls.

```
// ...somewhereinside you Hueckel class

public Tuple<int, int>[] myArray { get; set; }

// Initialize it
public void InitializeHueckel()
{
    CreateMyArray();
}

// and build it 
public void  CreateMyArray()
{
   myArray = new Tuple<int, int>[] {
             Tuple.Create(3, 1), Tuple.Create(4, 1), Tuple.Create(5, 1), 
             Tuple.Create(6, 1), Tuple.Create(7, 1), Tuple.Create(2, 2), 
             Tuple.Create(3, 2), Tuple.Create(4, 2), Tuple.Create(5, 2), 
             Tuple.Create(6, 2), Tuple.Create(7, 2), Tuple.Create(8, 2), 
             Tuple.Create(1, 3), Tuple.Create(2, 3), Tuple.Create(3, 3), 
             Tuple.Create(4, 3), Tuple.Create(5, 3), Tuple.Create(6, 3), 
             Tuple.Create(7, 3), Tuple.Create(8, 3), Tuple.Create(9, 3), 
             Tuple.Create(1, 4), Tuple.Create(2, 4), Tuple.Create(3, 4), 
             Tuple.Create(4, 4), Tuple.Create(5, 4), Tuple.Create(6, 4), 
             Tuple.Create(7, 4), Tuple.Create(8, 4), Tuple.Create(9, 4), 
             Tuple.Create(1, 5), Tuple.Create(1, 5), Tuple.Create(2, 5), 
             Tuple.Create(3, 5), Tuple.Create(4, 5), Tuple.Create(5, 5), 
             Tuple.Create(6, 5), Tuple.Create(7, 5), Tuple.Create(8, 5), 
             Tuple.Create(9, 5), Tuple.Create(1, 6), Tuple.Create(2, 6), 
             Tuple.Create(3, 6), Tuple.Create(4, 6), Tuple.Create(5, 6), 
             Tuple.Create(6, 6), Tuple.Create(7, 6), Tuple.Create(8, 6), 
             Tuple.Create(8, 6), Tuple.Create(1, 7), Tuple.Create(2, 7), 
             Tuple.Create(3, 7), Tuple.Create(4, 7), Tuple.Create(5, 7), 
             Tuple.Create(6, 7), Tuple.Create(7, 7), Tuple.Create(8, 7), 
             Tuple.Create(9, 7), Tuple.Create(2, 8), Tuple.Create(3, 8), 
             Tuple.Create(4, 8), Tuple.Create(5, 8), Tuple.Create(6, 8), 
             Tuple.Create(7, 8), Tuple.Create(8, 8), Tuple.Create(3, 9), 
             Tuple.Create(4, 9), Tuple.Create(5, 9), Tuple.Create(6, 9), 
             Tuple.Create(7, 9), 
             };
```

Inside your input_i_y you can use it as before:

```
return myArray[y].Item2;
```

Should remove some load of the stack.

Comment: I have done it and as you said it has reduced the load thanks.

Comment: @OutlawLemur it helped a bit and made me understand static better but it didnt solve my problem entirely but I accept it anyway

Answer (score 1):

The very beginning of your `hueckel_operator` method contains a hint of the likely source of your infinite recursion.

```
public void hueckel_operator(int counter2, int counter3)
        {      
            counter2 = counter4;
            counter3 = counter5;
```

You are, instead of *using* the values of your two parameters, immediately *assigning* them values that must come from fields that we can't see in your posted code.

The rest of the visible code doesn't even reference these parameters.

It's impossible to say certainly where the error is given the bits of code you've posted, but it's quite likely that these field values that really drive the logic are not changing, or not changing in a way that lets the recursion end.

I expect the root problem is that you can't understand your own code.  You should use meaningful variable names instead of `counter2`, `counter3`, etc., try to name your fields differently from your parameters, avoid reassigning your parameters, and define only parameters that are actually used.

And I'd try to get rid of the `goto` as well.

Comment: yes I really don't know why but I found such a solution to solve an error before but I fixed those messy parameters. But again it throws stack overflow but this time at mod_width = MyImage.Width % 5;
By the way hueckel_operator() is called 134 times and a() is called 1197 times. Strange thing it completes the first row(x=75 and y=5) of the image and I get all necessary values but at the 1/10 of the second row, it throws an stack overflow exception. I guess that means that it can not even reach termination condition.

Comment: Because termination condition is x=590 and y=790. I am pretty sure that it can not even reach termination condition because hueckel_operator is called just 134 times and it is pretty less to complete whole image. hueckel_operator has to be called (600/9)*(800/9) times.